# redirecting homepage without affecting other rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My current .htaccess is given below.

```
# Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php (if it's not an existing file/folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to redirect my homepage to another domain, but maintain all the /sub/directories. 
So changed the rules as below.

```
# Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php (if it's not an existing file/folder)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]    

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now all the /sub/directories are getting internel server error. Logs suggesting it's going on loops.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only for the next `RewriteRule`.

Use that:

```
# Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

#redirect
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301] 

# Send request via index.php (if it's not an existing file/folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks @croises. "RewriteRule ^ - [L]"  what is the use of this rule?

Comment: First I test with `-d` (for directory) and `-f` (file) if they exists or not. And `^` is a short for all cases. The `[L]` flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set if in this case file or directory exists.